# How to use count inside case

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please help me to count using case statement.

I want this result:

```
Equal : 50
GT : 25
LT : 15
```

Below is my code:

```
select Input,
      CASE
      when math = '=' then 
        count(case when Input = UDTarget then Input else 0 end)
      end as Equals,
      CASE
      when math = '>' then 
        count(case when ISNUMERIC(Input) < ISNUMERIC(UDTarget) then Input else 0 end)
      end as GT,
      CASE when math = '<' then 
        count(case when ISNUMERIC(Input) > ISNUMERIC(UDTarget) then Input else 0 end)  
      END as LT 
FROM [NEWSEMAKPI].[dbo].[NewCriteria] NC 
inner join [NEWSEMAKPI].[dbo].[UpdateData] UD ON UD.Cid = NC.Id 
where InputWeek='15' 
group by Input
```

Comment: What result are you getting currently? What is your input? Your expected output means nothing without it,.

Comment: i got this error:   Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Column 'NEWSEMAKPI.dbo.NewCriteria.Math' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: please do check here  on the way to ask question :https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: It would help if you include schema of source tables in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is shown because you didn't put `math` in your `group by` clause. So you should put it inside:

```
select Input,
      CASE
      when math = '=' then 
        count(case when Input = UDTarget then Input else 0 end)
      end as Equals,
      CASE
      when math = '>' then 
        count(case when ISNUMERIC(Input) < ISNUMERIC(UDTarget) then Input else 0 end)
      end as GT,
      CASE when math = '<' then 
        count(case when ISNUMERIC(Input) > ISNUMERIC(UDTarget) then Input else 0 end)  
      END as LT 
FROM [NEWSEMAKPI].[dbo].[NewCriteria] NC 
inner join [NEWSEMAKPI].[dbo].[UpdateData] UD ON UD.Cid = NC.Id 
where InputWeek='15' 
group by Input, math
```